# removeAllViews does not work on ViewGroup

Tags: android

This function is my function

```
private void previewCapturedImage(){

    Log.d("ChildCount", "content child count before:" + mSelectedImagesContainer.getChildCount());
    mSelectedImagesContainer.removeAllViews();
    Log.d("ChildCount", "content child count after:" + mSelectedImagesContainer.getChildCount());
    Iterator<Uri> iterator = mMedia.iterator();
    ImageInternalFetcher imageFetcher = new ImageInternalFetcher(this, 500);
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Uri uri = iterator.next();

        // showImage(uri);
        Log.i(TAG, " uri: " + uri);
        if (mMedia.size() >= 1) {
            mSelectedImagesContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        View imageHolder = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.media_layout, null);

        // View removeBtn = imageHolder.findViewById(R.id.remove_media);
        // initRemoveBtn(removeBtn, imageHolder, uri);
        ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView) imageHolder.findViewById(R.id.media_image);

        if (!uri.toString().contains("content://")) {
            // probably a relative uri
            uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(uri.toString()));
        }

        imageFetcher.loadImage(uri, thumbnail);

        mSelectedImagesContainer.addView(imageHolder);

        // set the dimension to correctly
        // show the image thumbnail.
        int wdpx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 150, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int htpx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        thumbnail.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(wdpx, htpx));
    }
}
```

In the second line `mSelectedImagesContainer.removeAllViews()`, I am trying to clear the view of all existing children views. but it is not working as expected.

So basically this parent container mSelectedImagesContainer has a horizonal list of images that was passed from one more activity.

Also the output of the logging is accurate, it clears all the childviews but for some reason main activity still shows the old images that were previously selected in the viewgroup.

If anything else is needed please let me know. I have not posted the full code since it's quite large. Anyways, if needed I can post it here with the XML's.

Just an info, I am working on a `poly-clicker` library, for the image picker and a custom scroll view for images.

**Screenshots**

1) Here I selected 2 images

[image]

2) And these images displayed perfectly in the scroll view

[image]

3) Now i selected a different set of images i.stack.imgur.com/sw5hz.jpg

[image]

4) However, the first selection is still not cleared from the view i.stack.imgur.com/lKovI.jpg

[image]

Comment: 3) Now i selected a different set of images
http://i.stack.imgur.com/sw5hz.jpg

4) However, the first selection is still not cleared from the view
http://i.stack.imgur.com/lKovI.jpg

Comment: Use the 'edit' button to the bottom-left corner of your post to add more relevant information.

Comment: @Shaishav i do not have enough points to add more links

Comment: Just to be sure:....are you sure you are not adding those images again in the iterator loop?

Comment: oh.. possible. i will debug and get back to you.

Comment: @Shaishav that did the job. I guess.. i cannot even upvote your answer.

Comment: Yeah...no points on comments...

Comment: @Shaishav Thank you. That did it then..cheers :) stupid me

Answer (score 0):

Answer posted in comments by @Shaishav, where the iterator was passed with a hashset which needed to be cleared, so reinitializing the variable **"mMedia"** did the job.